# python os.walk() problems

Tags: python-2.7

I faced some problems when I used os.walk()

Here is my code:

```
import os

premise_source_dir = 'C:/Users/xujia_000/Desktop/Final_data/eclipse_data/test/test_premise/'
for (premise_root,premise_subdirs,premise_files) in os.walk(premise_source_dir):
    print premise_root
    print premise_subdirs
    print premise_files
```

The result is:
[image]

It doesn't really get the premise_root and premise_files.

So, maybe there is something wrong with my code?

Comment: What were you expecting to happen differently?  It printed the three things you asked for - the directory name, an empty list of subdirectories, and a list of files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you join `premise_root` and a filename in `premise_files`, you will get the absolute path of that file.

```
import os

premise_source_dir = 'C:/Users/xujia_000/Desktop/Final_data/eclipse_data/test/test_premise/'
for (premise_root,premise_subdirs,premise_files) in os.walk(premise_source_dir):
    for f in premise_files:
        print os.path.join(premise_root, f)
```

The above code will print the absolute path of every file in `premise_source_dir`, recursively.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it's exactly what I'm looking for!